# How to save to file all the syn packets?

Tags: networking, tcpdump

I need to have some statics (for test purpose ) on syn packet that was recieved.
I got lost with the available tools - ethreal. tshark.tcpdumt.

I want the simple tool that will not dump the complete packet only by pattern (in my case only ip, but some case i will also need payload) .
Which one from the above (or another) do the job?
If you have some patient i will be tankful for you to reference about the differences between them. didnt find good one.

I am running on Ubuntu.
The tool and the filter and the pattern all need to be from command line.
pattern can be - ip.src ip.payload

Thank you

Comment: [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org/) will be fine, but we need an example of the patterns / payload you are trying to capture.

Comment: update question. need command line tool

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following tcpdump command will save all the packets to a file which have the SYN flag set and are sent to the IP address stored in the environmental variable MYIP:

```
MYIP=172.16.1.2
sudo tcpdump -w /tmp/syn_packets "tcp[tcpflags] & tcp-syn != 0 and dst $MYIP"
```

List of unique host/ports from the dump can be listed with the following command:

```
tcpdump -nr /tmp/syn_packets |cut -d " " -f 3 |uniq
```

List of packet counts per host/port can be listed with the following command:

```
tcpdump -nr /tmp/syn_packets |cut -d " " -f 3 |uniq -c
```

The packet contents will be stored in the tmp file. You can see a hex dump of the packet data with the -x option:

```
tcpdump -xr /tmp/syn_packets
```

You can dump the contents of packets from specific IPs with the following command:

```
REMOTEIP=6.6.6.6
tcpdump -xr /tmp/syn_packets "src $REMOTEIP"
```